# Getting syntax error when trying to create dictionary of object

Tags: javascript

I am getting an array of objects from API like below :

```
[
{
    jobId:100,
    jobName: "Java",
      cities:[
      {
           cityId:10,
           name : "chicago"
      },
      {
         statusId:11,
         name : "miami"
      }]
  },
  {
    jobId:101,
    jobName: "Python",
      cities:[
      {
           cityId:11,
           name : "california"
      },
      {
         cityId:12,
         name : "texas"
      }]
  }
]
```

I want to access a city name of particular job like below :

```
var jobId = 101;
var cityId = 12;
var texas = jobDict[jobId].cityDict[cityId] // output: texas
```

Code:

```
angular.forEach(response.data, function (data) {
        if (jobsDict[data.jobId] == undefined) {
                jobsDict[data.jobId] = [];
        }
        angular.forEach(data.cities, function (city) {
                jobsDict[data.jobId].push({
                    cityDic[city.cityId]: city.name // syntax error here saying unexpected token
                   });
                });
            });
```

I am trying to create a dictionary of jobs and inside a job dictionary, a dictionary of cities.

Can someone please help me fix the issue and achieve the desired output?

Comment: I know this is a bit pedantic, but be aware that there's no such thing as a dictionary in JavaScript. Most people mean Object, but it could also mean Array, Set, or Map.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I see but I am just trying to build something like this: Job[101].Cities[12]. I don't want to loop this array of objects to filter out job first based on job id and then city based on city id. Thats why trying to create a look up for Job and city

Comment: Try using the `filter` or `find` array methods?

Comment: this will never work, first you need to find index of jobId, which in sample given that would be 1, then you need to find index cityId, which in this case would be 1.

Comment: @Nonik:I already have the jobid and cityid value and if I can build the dictionary of JobId and CityId then why cant I directly access the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jobsDict` is an array and therefore uses 0-based indexing, not `jobID` keys.

Likewise for the nested `cities`.

```js
let jobDict = [{
  jobId: 100,
  jobName: "Java",
  cities: [{
    cityId: 10,
    name: "chicago"
  }, {
    statusId: 11,
    name: "miami"
  }]
}, {
  jobId: 101,
  jobName: "Python",
  cities: [{
    cityId: 11,
    name: "california"
  }, {
    cityId: 12,
    name: "texas"
  }]
}];

let jobId = 101;
let cityId = 12;
let texas =
  jobDict.find(job => job.jobId === jobId)
  .cities.find(city => city.cityId === cityId)
  .name;

console.log(texas);
```

Following up on your comments, if you're really concerned about performance (which you shouldn't be unless you have 1000's of entries), here's how you can transform the original structure to a 'dictionary' structure that uses the job & city IDs as keys:

```js
let jobs = [{
    jobId: 100,
    jobName: "Java",
    cities: [{
        cityId: 10,
        name: "chicago"
    }, {
        cityId: 11,
        name: "miami"
    }]
}, {
    jobId: 101,
    jobName: "Python",
    cities: [{
        cityId: 11,
        name: "california"
    }, {
        cityId: 12,
        name: "texas"
    }]
}];

let jobsById = Object.fromEntries(jobs.map(({jobId, jobName, cities}) =>
        [jobId, {jobName, cities: Object.fromEntries(cities.map(({cityId, name}) => [cityId, name]))}]));

// Equivalent using traditional for loops.
let jobsById2 = {};
for (job of jobs) {
  let cities = {};
  for (city of job.cities)
    cities[city.cityId] = city.name;
  jobsById2[job.jobId] = {jobName: job.jobName, cities};
}

console.log(jobsById[101].cities[12]);
console.log(jobsById2[101].cities[12]);
```

Comment: This will loop everytime right whenever I want to look for a particular city inside a particular job?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you're concerned with performance because you have 1000's of cities and jobs, then you can map the arrays to objects with jobId and cityId keys.

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow Please be aware that if `jobDict.find` returns null, then accessing `.cities` could throw an error.

Comment: Actually, I have to access the value from this array of objects that is why I am trying to build the dictionary to avoid looping every time I need to access the city based on the job.

Comment: I want to build dictionary of job and inside job, I want to build dictionary of city so that I can directly access the job and city without having to loop everytime I need to do this at so many place

Comment: I think calling it a dictionary is what is confusing things. `jobDict` is an array, which will need to be looped over to access items. Consider using an Object, Set, or Map instead?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow added an example of how to transform the arrays (keyed by index) to objects (keyed by job/city IDs).

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me, is it possible to simplify the last code to use simple for loop just for my understanding, please?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow added, but when you have a chance, you should look into `Object.fromEntries`, `array.prototype.map`, and destructuring syntax; they're all pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```js
const jobArray = [{
    jobId: 100,
    jobName: "Java",
    cities: [{
        cityId: 10,
        name: "chicago"
      },
      {
        cityId: 11,
        name: "miami"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    jobId: 101,
    jobName: "Python",
    cities: [{
        cityId: 11,
        name: "california"
      },
      {
        cityId: 12,
        name: "texas"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function index_job_array_A(jobArray) {
  return jobArray.reduce(
    (acc, item) => Object.assign(acc, {
      [item.jobId]: Object.assign({}, item, {
        cities: item.cities.reduce(
          (acc, item) => Object.assign(acc, { [item.cityId]: item }),
          {}
        )
      })
    }),
    {}
  );
};

function index_job_array_B(jobArray) {
  let indexed_jobs = {};
  
  jobArray.forEach(function(job) {
    let indexed_cities = {};
    
    job.cities.forEach(function(city) {
      indexed_cities[city.cityId] = city;
    });
    
    indexed_jobs[job.jobId] = { ...job, cities: indexed_cities };
  });

  return indexed_jobs;
};

const jobDictA = index_job_array_A(jobArray);
const jobDictB = index_job_array_B(jobArray);

console.log(jobDictA['100'].cities['10']);
console.log(jobDictB['100'].cities['10']);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it using more simplified syntax? Its hard to understand right now. If possible please